# Base64 encoded file becomes empty string on HTTP POST request

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I'm trying to send an array of objects to a server that each contain a base64 encoded .png image that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        itemName: '...',
        itemType: '...',
        price: 123,
        purchaseUrl: '...',
        imageBase64: 'data:image/png;base64,...'
    },
    {...},
    {...}
]
```

All my data is where I need it to be right up until the point that I create the POST request, and then all the base64 images become blank.

```
{
  "newMerchandise": [
    {
      "imageBase64":"",
      "itemName":"asdasd",
      "itemType":"asdsad",
      "purchaseUrl":"asdsad",
      "price":123
    }
  ],
  "artistRef":"eddcc4ec-4e7c-4e0a-916e-3b845d9b713d"
}
```

The Angular Injectable that sends the http request looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MerchandiseApiService implements MerchandiseApiServiceInterface {
  private readonly _http: HttpClient;

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    this._http = http;
  }

  public addItems(newMerchandise: Array<NewMerchandiseUploadRequestClass>, artistRef: string): Observable<ApiResponse<string>> {
    console.log(newMerchandise); // base64 string exists still on each item.

    return this._http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/merchandise/add-items`, {
        newMerchandise: newMerchandise,
        artistRef: artistRef
      })
        .pipe(
            map((response: MusicPortalApiResponse<string>): MusicPortalApiResponse<string> => {
              return {
                response: response.response,
                hasError: response.hasError,
                exception: response.exception
              }
            })
        )
  }
}
```

I've tried using formData which did the same, I tried a method that stringified the Base64 string before being attached to the FormData, which worked but then I eneded up with something like this:

```
"\"imageBase64"\":"\"data:image/png;base64,..."\",
```

Which just isn't clean at all.

I'm wondering if it's a headers thing?

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 165
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:5000
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:4200/user/add-new-merchandise/eddcc4ec-4e7c-4e0a-916e-3b845d9b713d?artistRef=eddcc4ec-4e7c-4e0a-916e-3b845d9b713d
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36
X-AUTH-TOKEN: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJjMWM3OWRjNy1hMTdmLTRkNTktODBhNS1kNjM0YWVlNzAzNWYiLCJleHAiOjE1NzM3Mjk1MzMsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMC8iLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjUwMDAvIn0.WTKdP6cFrUGrDq4YnX5IlqOkwP3-YRyhMrNpvQZzIWs
```

**EDIT**

I've added this screenshot from the debugger on the server that shows the Base64 string is blank

[image]

Comment: How do you know that imageBase64 is blank? Is it from the server or from the request in the browser dev tool?

Comment: It's actually both. I pasted in the request actually made from the Dev tools and when I use a debugger on the server I get 

ImageBase64 = (string) ""

Comment: stepping through the debugger, the request hits every method that processes the images and passes a blank string to them.

Comment: Is there anything in imageBase64 in the Dev tools? Can you try  console.log(JSON.stringify(newMerchandise)); ?

Comment: When using JSON.stringify, I get this 
[{"imageBase64":"","itemName":"asdasdad","itemType":"asdsad","purchaseUrl":"asdasdasd","price":123}]

Comment: That means something is wrong with your imageBase64. How did you construct them?

Comment: I did manage to get a fix for it and I'll post that in a second :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't manage to figure out what was going on... However, a friend of mine just recommended having a file upload directive, so after a huge refactor and gitting rid of a cr*p tonne of code, I ended up with this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, forwardRef, HostListener, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[fileUpload]',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => FileUploadDirective),
            multi: true,
        }
    ]
})
export class FileUploadDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {
    private _onChange: Function;
    private _onTouched: Function;
    private readonly _renderer: Renderer2;
    private readonly _element: ElementRef;
    constructor(renderer: Renderer2, element: ElementRef) {
        this._renderer = renderer;
        this._element = element;
    }
    public registerOnChange(fn: Function): void {
        this._onChange = fn;
    }
    public registerOnTouched(fn: Function): void {
        this._onTouched = fn;
    }
    public setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this._renderer.setProperty(this._element.nativeElement, 'disabled', isDisabled);
    }
    public writeValue(value: any): void {
        this._renderer.setProperty(this._element.nativeElement, 'value', value);
    }
    @HostListener('change', ['$event.target.value'])
    public onValueChange(): void {
        const file = this._element.nativeElement.files[0];
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (result): any => this._onChange(result.target['result']);
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

Which then gets attached to my file upload form input:

```
 <div class="my-2">
   <div>
     <label for="file-input">Choose an item image</label>
     <input id="file-input" class="file-input" accept="image/*" type="file" [formControlName]="newMerchandiseFormEnum.ITEM_IMAGE" fileUpload>
   </div>
</div>
```

Which also meant I didn't have to have any unreasonable logic around my FormControl either so this is a win win.

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {NewMerchandiseFormEnum} from '../../../../models/form-enums/new-merchandise-form.enum';
import {Artist} from '../../../../models/domain/artist.class';
import {NewMerchandiseUploadRequest} from '../../../../models/api/new-merchandise-upload-request.class';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-merch-form',
  templateUrl: 'new-merchandise-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['new-merchandise-form.component.scss']
})

export class NewMerchandiseFormComponent {
  public newMerchandiseForm: FormGroup;
  public newMerchandiseFormEnum: typeof NewMerchandiseFormEnum = NewMerchandiseFormEnum;
  @Input() public artist: Artist;
  @Output() public onFormSubmitted: EventEmitter<NewMerchandiseUploadRequest>;

  constructor() {
    this.onFormSubmitted = new EventEmitter<NewMerchandiseUploadRequest>();

    this.newMerchandiseForm = new FormGroup({
      [this.newMerchandiseFormEnum.ITEM_NAME]: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      [this.newMerchandiseFormEnum.ITEM_TYPE]: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      [this.newMerchandiseFormEnum.ITEM_PRICE]: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      [this.newMerchandiseFormEnum.ITEM_IMAGE]: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]), // It just gets attached here as a string now. 
      [this.newMerchandiseFormEnum.PURCHASE_URL]: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    })
  }

  public emitNewMerchForm(): void {
    this.onFormSubmitted.emit(this.newMerchandiseForm.value);
    this.newMerchandiseForm.reset();
  }
}
```